# Update same table clolumn with value after it has been subtracted

Tags: mysql

I would like to get values in duration column from main_table, subtract 1 (one) from each value in the column, then update the same column with the difference (result after subtract) e.g

```
main_table (before any operation)
--------------------------------
id     duration
1        x
2        y
3        z

main_table (after update operation)
--------------------------------
id     duration
1        x - 1
2        y - 1
3        z - 1
```

here is what I have tried so far and failed

```
UPDATE main_table mt, (SELECT duration - 1 AS remaining
                FROM main_table mt1
               ) mt1
SET mt.duration = mt1.remaining 
WHERE mt.id = mt1.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need sub-query for this, it could be done with single update statement

```
update main_table
set 
duration = duration - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use your column like this, this will update your column value as you require.
Check it, may help you.

```
UPDATE main_table mt 
SET mt.duration = mt.duration -1
```